# GA: How much time have my 100 most "obsessed" users spent on my site

Tags: google-analytics

Does Google Analytics have enough information to answer the question of how much time have my top 100 users spent on my site? I don't need their user information, I don't care about ID or name which I know it doesn't even have. Just the identification of individual users by the cookie GA uses, and a report of how much time the top 100 loyal users spent on my site.

is such a thing possible at all with GA?

Comment: Do you mean top 100 in terms of sessions? If so, perhaps you could create a new segment on the Audience > Behaviour > Engagement report containing the minimum number of sessions that identify your top 100 users?

Comment: Have you looked at GA User Explorer ?https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment on Colwin's answer:

> I don't need google if I have to track this for GA, I just hoped it already has this information such as "page visit duration" on a per-user, ongoing basis. If I had to feed Google that information myself, I can feed my own database and run analytics on it. Thanks anyway.

The [`Google analytics sessions`](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en) is

> a group of user interactions with your website that take place within a given time frame. For example a single session can contain multiple page views, events, social interactions, and ecommerce transactions.

[image]

[Average session duration](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en) will be calculated as

```
total duration of all sessions / number of sessions
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is available from GA out of the box. But you can build something like this with [Custom Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) available within GA

This will let you setup and send custom metrics dimensions for users that you can then create reports for.

Google Analytics doesn’t allow you to out in PII but random visitor id's should be fine. You can then compare against your own database outside of GA if needed too.
This will allow tracking the same visitor even without them being logged in to your site.

Sending the custom dimensions could possibly look like this.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension5':  '1234567890'
});
```

You get 20 free custom dimension slots with GA and 200 with GA 360 -> More info [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)

Comment: yeah, I don't need google if I have to track this for GA, I just hoped it already has this information such as "page visit duration" on a per-user, ongoing basis. If I had to feed Google that information myself, I can feed my own database and run analytics on it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article has what you are looking for

https://webanalyticsguy.com/2018/01/18/google-analytics-capture-client-id-reporting-purposes/

It shows how to capture the client id which is a decent way to track a specific user. And goes further to explain how to associate that with a metric, in this case the author uses PageView.

You could change this to Average Session Duration or another metric that gives you a sense of time spent.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are looking for something like this:
http://www.analytics-ninja.com/blog/2015/02/real-time-page-google-analytics.html
You can get the counts of the users on your site. You can get the seconds they spent on your website page.
I guess this answer will be helpful too: https://qr.ae/TWpkI0